# Using eldarion-ajax/bootstrap-ajax with laravel. How to make use of the events?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to enrich the user's web experience with Ajax on my webpage. I'm used to do Ajax calls with jQuery but i came across the eldarion-ajax (former bootstrap-ajax -> https://github.com/eldarion/eldarion-ajax) and thought that this might be a good idea to use. But know a question arise at the beginning. I give you an example:
I created a form with:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/contact/send', 'class' => 'form-outside form-contact ajax')) }}
```

Class 'ajax' should now made the form sensible for ajax calls.
I now turn to the JavaScript code and use one of the event handlers eldarion gives me:

```
$('.form-contact').on("eldarion-ajax:begin", function(evt, $el) {
        $.post(
            $( this ).prop( 'action' ),
            {
                "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val()
            },
            function( data ) {
                //here comes the response
            },
            'json'
        );
    });
```

So as i understand it, this event (`eldarion-ajax:begin`) gets fired at the beginning of the request when someone now clicks ob submit in the form. As I use the $.post function to actually send the data of the form to laravel's custom controller class i can use the response the controller sends back to me within the `function( data ) {}` section.

Why and how can i make use of the other eldarion events, such as `eldarion-ajax:success` then? As i understand it with eldarion-ajax:success i should use the data that gets back to me from the controller in case everything was okay. Does that make any sense? Should i do not use $.post and handle this in a different way with eldarion? How?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the library, you don't actually need to make the custom request - since you already have specified `ajax` class. From the documentation

> All events are triggered on the element that is declared to be ajax

Moreover, several elements can be declared to be ajax, using lib's events make easy to handle by defining single event handler (perhaps event delegation), for eg. [from the doc](https://github.com/eldarion/eldarion-ajax#eldarion-ajaxsuccess)

```
$(document).on("eldarion-ajax:success", [data-prepend-inner], function(evt, $el, data) {
    // different actions can be performed based on different elements
    var $node = $($el.data("prepend-inner"));
    $node.data(data.html + $node.html());
});
```

Comment: Hey code-jaff,
yes thank you. But if I use eldarion-ajax:begin i have then to check which element has been fired and do the necessary actions like $.post for transferring the submitted data to the controller script on php side, or am i wrong here? The action always depend on the element where the ajax call has been fired. If i use $.post then, i have a response from the server within the $.post function and do not need eldarion-ajax:success or am i missing something?